# In 3D point groups, does $[\Gamma_{e}\otimes\Gamma_e] = \Gamma_{Rot_z} \forall$ degenerate $\Gamma_e$ hold in general?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, mg.metric-geometry

In the following I am referring to groups exclusively [describing 3D point symmetries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_group). I use the [Schönflies notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_notation) for groups and their elements and the [Mulliken symbols](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MullikenSymbols.html) to describe their irreducible representations. A representative (e.g. $\mathrm{C}_{\infty v}$, $\mathrm{D}_{\infty h}$ and very high order groups are missing)  list of these groups and their characters (using only real characters, however (as is custom in Chemistry, and often in Physics)) I have used in these considerations is [here](http://www.gernot-katzers-spice-pages.com/character_tables/). (And please excuse me for my clumsy language as I am not a specialist in this subject.)

> **Conjecture 1** The antisymmetric part of the direct product of a degenerate irreducible representation (this is exactly all of type: $E$, $T$, $G$ and $H$) is identical to the representation that transforms like the rotation about the (highest order) axis of symmetry.

Example: In $\mathrm{D}_{5d}$ the rotation around the 5-fold axis transforms like $\mathrm{A}_{2g}$. The group contains four different *degenerate* irreducible representations: $E_{1g}, E_{2g}, E_{1u}, E_{2u}$. For these we have
$$ E_{1g}\otimes E_{1g} = E_{2g}\otimes E_{2g} = E_{1u}\otimes E_{1u} =  E_{2u} \otimes E_{2u} = A_{1g} \oplus [A_{2g}] \oplus E_{2g} ,$$
Whereby the brackets ([ ]) denote the anti-symmetric part of the direct product. This does not contradict the Conj. 1.

> **Conjecture 2** When we here descend in symmetry along a component of the direct product of this degenerate representation with itself which is not contained in the anti-symmetric part nor which is the total symmetric representation we arrive in a new point group(s) and at new representations. The direct product of two of the representations which are thus yielded from the formerly degenerate representation, again is the representation of the rotation around the (highest order) axis of symmetry in (at least one of the) new group(s).

Example: The only non-totally symmetric representation and non anti-symmetric part of direct product of the degenerate representations in  $\mathrm{D}_{5d}$ with itself is $E_{2g}$. If I distort $\mathrm{D}_{5d}$ along $E_{2g}$ I get $\mathrm{C}_{2h}$ or $\mathrm{C}_i$. Now lets look at $E_{1g}$ for example this splits into $2A_{g}$ in $\mathrm{C}_{i}$. And 
$$ A_{g} \otimes A_{g} = A_{g}$$

Now trivially, rotations in $\mathrm{C}_{i}$ transform like $A_g$. This, however does not work in $\mathrm{C}_{2h}$, the other possible symmetry descent from $\mathrm{D}_{5d}$ along $E_{2g}$.

It would be important for certain questions about molecular response properties to know if these two Conjectures are true and how to show them in this case. Maybe its even a trivial result, which I just cannot see, due to being too inexperienced in that field. In any case it would have interesting chemical consequences worth publishing (along with exemplary data).

My naive idea about how one could prove this is, the following, I suppose its easy to show that the totally symmetric representation must be contained in any "direct square" of a representation. Now those degenerate representations all (as far as I understand) contain complex characters. Then I suppose in a similar argument as for the totally symmetric representation one might be able to show that once there are complex characters, that forces certain characters of the decomposition terms to be $-1$. And that should than be about those making the representation a rotation. The second conjecture might be some consequence of the first one (I'd hope).

I will be very grateful for any comments that help to enlighten me. And in case of substantial and worthy outcome I'd offer co-authorship.